# New value is same as old value if not passed for update in oracle before update trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have created a before insert/update trigger as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "AUDIT_TABLE_TRIG" BEFORE
  INSERT OR UPDATE ON AUDIT_TABLE FOR EACH ROW BEGIN :NEW.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE:=SYSDATE;
  IF :new.LAST_MODIFIED_BY = NULL THEN
    :NEW.LAST_MODIFIED_BY :=SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER');
  END IF;
END;
```

Requirement was to update last_modified_by value same as logged in user instead of OS user, if last_modified_by is null then take OS user id. When i was updating this table from UI it worked fine. Last modified by value is coming as logged in user id (as it was getting passed in update statement).
But when i updated some other column in AUDIT_TABLE from sql developer, *:new.last_modified_by* is never coming *null* instead it has value same as *:old.last_modified_by* 
Que1- I have handled this scenario in not so good way as

```
 IF :new.LAST_MODIFIED_BY = NULL || :OLD.LAST_MODIFIED_BY !=SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER') THEN
            :NEW.LAST_MODIFIED_BY :=SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER');
 END IF;
```

Is there other good way I can handle this? 
Que2:
I came across this scenario and i got surprised. is it a standard behavior for oracle triggers that new variables have old values if they are not changed while updating?

Comment: `new variables have old values if they are not changed while updating` ... if the old and new value are the same, then isn't this what you would logically expect?

Comment: If i am not changing column value, i was expecting :new .column to be null as its not really in the context or i have not passed anything as new value..but looks like I missed this while writing trigger.

Comment: `:new.LAST_MODIFIED_BY = NULL` may not produce the desired result, so the right way to write this would be `:new.LAST_MODIFIED_BY is NULL`. From my past experiences `val = NULL` is less reliable way as compared to `val is NULL` ( or `val is NOT NULL`).

Comment: Thank Annjawn. I will do that.

Comment: Unrelated, but: are you aware that `OS_USER` is an information provided by the client _application_. I can connect to any Oracle server using `Krishnat Molawade` as the OS user name. Don't rely on that!

Comment: In this case OS_USER will be taken from server machine, so we need not be worried ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **UPDATING** predicate, that would probably meet your requirement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "AUDIT_TABLE_TRIG" BEFORE
  INSERT OR UPDATE ON AUDIT_TABLE FOR EACH ROW BEGIN :NEW.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE:=SYSDATE;
  IF NOT UPDATING('LAST_MODIFIED_BY') THEN
    :NEW.LAST_MODIFIED_BY :=SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I needed null condition as well, so handled it as  IF NOT UPDATING('LAST_MODIFIED_BY') OR :NEW.LAST_MODIFIED_BY is null THEN
    :NEW.LAST_MODIFIED_BY :=SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','OS_USER');
 END IF;